# SQL - looking for matches with one to many table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables, one with orders that looks something like this

| Order ID | Coupon | BIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | C1 | B1 |
| O2 | C2 | B3 |

| Coupon | BIN |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | B1 |
| C1 | B2 |
| C2 | B2 |

Now I want to check if the BINs in the first table are not present in the second table against the coupon.

How do I write a Redshift query for this?

For example, my output from the sample tables would be O2, C2, B3

Comment: Your output should be `O2,C2,B3` or `O1,C2,B3`

Comment: Do you mean the expected result should be "O2, C2, B3"?

Comment: Fixed the mistake in expected output, thank you @Abinash

Answer (score 1):

```
select o.*
from order o
leff join coupon c on o.bin=c.bin and o.coupon=c.coupon
where c.bin is null
```

Answer (score 0):

An anti-join will find the rows of the first table which `BIN` value is not present in the second one. For example:

```
select o.*
from o
leff join c on c.bin = o.bin
where c.bin is null
```

Comment: In this above query, how are you matching for coupon code? Won't this return any case where coupon has a mismatch?